# Can DEF Pipeline Batches run outside the CM?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I have DEF tenant configured to pull contacts from D365 and push activities to D365. Trying to figure out High Availability solution to keep these processes running. Can we run the pipeline batches in one of the CDs, instead of the CM? Trying to avoid having a HA option for the CM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is possible or not but it is not a good idea to run the DEF pipeline batches in one of the CD servers as there are lots of limitations based on best practices such as the master and web database will not be available on CD server, a publish can override the Sitecore changes. But with regards to your original problem, you can use `Data Exchange Framework Remote SDK`.

`Data Exchange Framework Remote SDK` allows *pipeline batches*, *pipelines*, and *other framework components* to run outside of the Sitecore server. This can significantly reduce the load on your Sitecore server by moving much I/O and other processing to a separate machine.

When using the remote SDK, Sitecore’s role in synchronization processes is limited to the configuration. Sitecore items are used to configure framework components, but the framework components themselves run within the application domain that is using the remote SDK.

There are some **limitations to using DEF Remote SDK**, which you need to take care of before using it-

- The component must not have any dependencies on APIs that are only available on the Sitecore server.
- Can not run Sitecore pipelines (Data Exchange Framework provides its own pipeline implementation that can be used instead)
- Can not read anything from Sitecore configuration files
- Can not use any type defined in Sitecore assemblies (Sitecore.Services.Core.dll is the one exception)

For implementing a remote client use this reference - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/def/v1.4.1/remote-sdk/implementing-a-remote-client/index.html

Reference - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/data-exchange-framework-remote-client.html